# I want to sent mail through SendGrid to a particular id which i get from sequelize query but the mails can not sent to that fetched mail from a table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sendgrid

```
Leave.create({
        leaveType: leaveType,
        fromDate: fromDate,
        toDate: toDate,
        emailId: emailId,
        reason: reason,
        reportTo: reportTo,
        userId: userId
    })
    LeaveReq.create({
        empName: userId,
        appliedFrom: fromDate,
        apliedTo: toDate,
        leaveType: leaveType,
        status: req.body.status,
        reqTo: reportTo
    })
    .then(result =>{
        transporter.sendMail({
            to: EmpList.findOne({attributes:['profEmail'],where:{firstName: reportTo}}),
            from: 'CTHRM@coretechies.com,',
            subject: 'You recieved a user request',
            html: `<p>please check your app to take action on this request</p>
            `
          });
        res.status(201).json({message: 'leave updated', userId: result.id, status: '1'})
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        if(!err.statusCode){
            err.statusCode = 500;
        }
        next(err);
    });
```

i get this error

```
node:9440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Missing destination email
    at Request._callback (D:\ct-work\cthrm_api\node_modules\sendgrid\lib\sendgrid.js:88:25)
    at Request.self.callback (D:\ct-work\cthrm_api\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\ct-work\cthrm_api\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\ct-work\cthrm_api\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1200:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
(node:9440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
```

> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:9440) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

suggest some method to sent mail through a sql query in 'to' section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in this code:

1) To property of `sendMail` supported types are `string | string[]`.

I.e you can either send `"a@domain, b@domain"` or `["a@domain", "b@domain"]`.

The returned value of

```
EmpList.findOne({attributes:['profEmail'],where:{firstName: reportTo}});
```

is a `promise<pending>` because you aren't waiting for the result. You're actually assigning `to` to: `Promise<pending>` which is not: `string | string[]`.

If you will use an `async` function you can do:

```
const emp = await EmpList.findOne({attributes:['profEmail'],where:{firstName: reportTo}})

transporter.sendMail({
    to: emp,
    from: 'CTHRM@coretechies.com,',
    subject: 'You recieved a user request',
    html: `<p>please check your app to take action on this request</p>`
});
res.status(201).json({message: 'leave updated', userId: result.id, status: '1'})
```

and then assign `res` to `to` property of `sendMail`

2) `sendMail` returns a promise as well, so you must wait for the result of the promise and catch an error if one is thrown:

```
transporter.sendMail({
        to: EmpList.findOne({attributes:['profEmail'],where:{firstName: reportTo}}),
        from: 'CTHRM@coretechies.com,',
        subject: 'You recieved a user request',
        html: `<p>please check your app to take action on this request</p>`
})
.then((data) => conosle.log(data))
.catch((e) => console.error(e);
```

That is the reason you get:

> (node:9440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:9440) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

**EDIT**:

Full example with async function.
let assume that all this code is written under function, let assume this function is called `create`.

```js
async function create(req, res, next) {
    try {
        let leaveRes = await Leave.create({
            leaveType: leaveType,
            fromDate: fromDate,
            toDate: toDate,
            emailId: emailId,
            reason: reason,
            reportTo: reportTo,
            userId: userId
        });
        let leaveReqRes = await LeaveReq.create({
            empName: userId,
            appliedFrom: fromDate,
            apliedTo: toDate,
            leaveType: leaveType,
            status: req.body.status,
            reqTo: reportTo
        });

        const emp = await findEmp({firstName: reportTo});
        await sendMailToEmp(emp);
        // If you made it to here, everything succeeded.
        res.status(201).json({message: 'leave updated', userId: result.id, status: '1'});

    } catch(e) {
        console.error('Problem in executing create', e);
        throw e; // or next (e) depends on how it is built.
    }
}

function findEmp(filter) {
    return EmpList.findOne({
        attributes:['profEmail'],
        where: filter
    });
}

function sendEmailToEmp(emp) {
    try {
        transporter.sendMail({
            to: emp,
            from: 'CTHRM@coretechies.com,',
            subject: 'You recieved a user request',
            html: `<p>please check your app to take action on this request</p>`
        });
    } catch(e) {
        console.error('Problem in sending mail', e);
    }
}
```

Comment: No worries. I added a full example of how it should have been done with the es6 async function. Read about them.